# Lazy load images in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, image, lazy-loading

I have some 50 custom cells in my UITableView. I want to display an image and a label in the cells where I get the images from URLs.

I want to do a lazy load of images so the UI does not freeze up while the images are being loaded. I tried getting the images in separate threads but I have to load each image every time a cell becomes visible again (Otherwise reuse of cells shows old images)

Apps like Facebook load images only for cells currently visible and once the images are loaded, they are not loaded again. Can someone please tell me how to duplicate this behavior.

Thanks.

*Edit*
Trying to cache images in an NSMutableDictionary object creates problems when the user scrolls fast. I am getting images only when scrolling completely stops and clearing out the cache on memory warning. But the app invariably gets a memory warning (due to size of images being cached) and clears the cache before reloading. If scrolling is very fast, it crashes.

Any other suggestions are welcome

Comment: @lostlnTransit hey did you find something how to develope like you hav e asked question i am also looking for that.

Comment: @Hrushikesh there are many examples available now on the internet which do this. Even the Facebook SDK provides an example of how to do with specifically with Facebook.

Comment: i have searched lot but i didn't get any idea. can you provide me some links with running examples?

Comment: You can check out these examples - https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/Hackbook, https://github.com/facebook/wishlist-mobile-sample

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Loading the images on a background thread is still a good idea.  If you didn't want to reload them each time, I'd suggest setting up an NSMutableDictionary and storing the images in there.  You could use some unique identifier, like the row ID or even the name of the image, as the key for each image.

When loading a cell, you'd send an objectForKey: message to the NSMutableDictionary to retrieve the image for that particular cell (based on your unique key for it).  If it returns nil, that means that the image is missing from the cache and you need your background image loading thread to go retrieve it.  Otherwise, you will get back the appropriate image for your table cell to display.  On a memory warning, you could clear out this cache of images with no adverse effects (aside from forcing them to be reloaded again on demand).

Comment: Thanks. But how do apps like Facebook and Box.net do it without any trouble! Thanks again for the response. I'll try this one and see if it has any adverse memory effects

Answer (score 4):

I have just successfully tackled the same problem by using a custom NSOperation to load the images in a queing fasion and stored them into a static NSMutableDictionary as a cache. Below is a link to the basis of the code I used to solve the problem.

[Loading remote images for UITableViewCell](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?s=a16436f953f04b1b122f47935333581e&t=553870&page=2)

Best to read all the threads in the forum to help you understand what's actually going on.

Comment: Hi Gcoop, the posts in the thread you've mentioned are very confusing. Can you share a consolidated code? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

lostInTransit,

I am having a similar problem and while exploring the many different possible solutions I found this blog post:

[davidgolightly.blogspot.com/2009/02/asynchronous-image-caching-with-iphone.html](http://davidgolightly.blogspot.com/2009/02/asynchronous-image-caching-with-iphone.html)

I would also suggest that you download the URLCache sample from the apple developer website:

[developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/samplecode/URLCache](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/samplecode/URLCache)/

And here is another post on the problem:

[www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/](http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/)

I'd love you to share your findings as well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings magma. I used Brad's suggestions along with the imageCache sample given here - http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/13/imagenamed-is-evil/

Answer (score 3):

Lazy loading is like synchronous type request.. means wait for respond

ego image button is solution for that..

ego image button is asynchronous type request..don't wait for respond..just display data at a time....

you can download folder from github....

add to your project...

in xib..at image view ,change class to ego image button...

make object of it in m file...

you can use.....

Answer (score 2):

For those who are interested, and are lazy like me, I would like to suggest an open source (MIT license) implementation of lazy/cached network of UIImageView images: [SDWebImage](http://cocoaobjects.com/sdwebimage/)

Answer (score 0):

UITableView with image caching and resizing/setting in background thread:

http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/08/12/gcd-example-updated-now-with-more-speed/

Comment: that is not a very good example because it doesn't handle the number of threads created ... read here http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-09-25-gcd-practicum.html

Answer (score 0):

This is [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues) about NSOperation with example that show how to Lazy load images in UITableViewCell