# avoid dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier to prevent UITableViewCell freezing

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uitableview

I am creating a custom UITableViewCell in which I am populating the cells with a JSon response of a web service. The problem is that the cell contains UIImage also which is creating problems when we scroll the cells (you can say freezing because of loading). I want to know the best practice of avoiding this behavior and also I want to know that is there any possibility that we don't use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` so we can prevent dequeueing of our cells.

Regards.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531482/lazy-load-images-in-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution to accomplish this by using HJCache Library. Have a look at this and up-vote if you like :). Here is the link > [HJCache Library](http://www.markj.net/hjcache-iphone-image-cache/)

Happy Coding!