# lazyload images on the iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, lazy-loading

Does anyone know of a good tutorial that shows how to lazy load images in a UITableView? I've searched online but the only one I found that looked like it did what I wanted was hard to follow because only parts of the code were shown and I'm new at this so I didn't understand how to hook everything up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lazy load images in UITableViewCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531482/lazy-load-images-in-uitableviewcell)

Comment: @jtbandes I'm looking for a tutorial on how to do it, the other question does not help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you check out the SDWebImage project on github, I use it for my table views when I need to load a remote image into the cells.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: Do you know of some tutorial? I'm very new at this and have a hard time understanding the code without some sort of direction

Comment: You really don't need a tutorial, if you download the code from the link, import the source into your project and all you need to do is include two files:  "UIImageView+WebCache.h", "SDWebImageManager.h", then you can call setImageWithURL:placeholderImage: onto your UIImageView and you're set

Comment: Aahh ok, I thought it was code I was going to have to implement for my project. That worked perfectly! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel suggested SDWebImage https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage, I don't know of any tutorial, but in amongst the KTPhotoBrowser samples there is one that uses SDWebImage that can show you how to do it https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser/tree/master/src/Sample/Classes/SDWebImageSample

If I remember correctly you need to import and use the SDWebImage UIImageView category and then pass the url to the cell and call

```
setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yoururl"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
```

when setting the cell image.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually followed it, but this one has plenty of positive commentary: http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/