# Getting so much load while displaying image from document directory folder iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios9

I am displaying images in UITableview from document directory folder but it's getting so much loading, how can I make it smooth. See below my code:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

If I convert the path into NSData then it also get so much load to display image in `UITableview`.

Any suggestion or any other way to display the image from document directory or any suggestion for smoothly loading images from document directory?

Comment: you should try using [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]; if you are loading bundled images

Answer (score 0):

Try [LazyTableImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code from Apple like Phil Kulak answered to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531482).